# Flexible affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety. $\text{Aut}(X)$ is the automorphism group of $X$. $\text{SAut}(X)$ is a subgroup spanned by all unipotent(image of additive group of field $K$) subgruops.

$X$ is called flexible if $\text{SAut}(X)$ act transitively on $X_{reg}$.

So I need to prove that if for affine variety $X$ there exists $f\in \mathbb{K}[X]^* \backslash \mathbb{K}^*$(nonconstant inversible regular function) then $X$ is not flexible.

I only got that if $f$ is nonconstant inversible function, then $f$ is non-constant on $X_{reg}$.

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p,q\in X_{reg}$, your hypothesis says that you can connect it via finitely many curves, all of which are images of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Since $\mathbb{A}^1$ has only constants as units, one easily sees that $f(p)=f(q)$. Thus, $f$ is constant on $X_{reg}$ and since this is a dense open set, $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Seems like this proof does not operate with SAut(X), like it proves that affine variety can not have inversuble regular functions. But affine varivety V(xy = 1) doesn't seem to suit this proof.

Comment: What is $SAut(X)$ for $xy=1$? Does it act transitively on $X$?

Comment: Indeed X is not flexible. Im just trying to see what breaks in your proof. We take $x\in \mathbb{C}[X] = \mathbb{C}[x,y] / (xy = 1)$. We take p = (1, 1) and q = (2, 0.5). How do we connect them via curve(I mean how can we build algebraic map $\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow X$)

Comment: I do not understand. You start with the assumptions, both flexible AND having non-trivial units and you reach a contradiction, so one of them has to fail.

Comment: I mean why there are infinite amount of curves connecting $p,q\in X_{reg}$?

Comment: I said finitely many curves, not infinitely many. This follows from the fact $SAut(X)$ is generated by images of affine line and since $\sigma(p)=q$ for some $\sigma\in SAut(X)$, connect identity to $\sigma$ using finitely many affine lines in $SAut(X)$.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks for being patient!